# Why does the Windows API offer 2 ways to "return" values?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, return, return-value

[For example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid), `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` takes in 2 values, a handle to a Window, and a pointer that receives the return value(the function also always `returns` the value).

What is the point of having both options? And when should I use a pointer to "return" a value versus actually returning it?

Comment: Those aren't the same value! One is a *thread* ID and the other is a *process* ID.

Comment: Does it? "A pointer to a variable that receives the process identifier" vs. "The return value is the identifier of the thread that created the window". I thought process and thread were two different things?

Comment: The signature is [`DWORD GetWindowThreadProcessId(HWND hWnd, LPDWORD lpdwProcessId);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid).  The return value is the  identifier of the thread that created the window.    lpdwProcessId is pointer to a variable that receives the process identifier.  They're two different things.  If you're not interested in the latter, just pass NULL for lpdwProcessId.

Comment: The very first sentence of the linked MSDN page states: "Retrieves the identifier of the thread that created the specified window and, optionally, the identifier of the process that created the window." So 1. The function returns two different things. 2. One of the things it returns is *optional* (and hence is set via an output parameter).

Comment: @mbj "*I thought process and thread were two different things?*" - they are. That is why the function returns two different values.

Answer (score 5):

They're not the same thing.

The "out argument" receives the process identifier. The return value is the thread identifier.

The real question is why two separate "give me valuez" mechanisms are used at all. You'd think two "out arguments" might be more consistent.

The answer is: humans. We make mistakes. We make inconsistent APIs. It happens.

Someone decided that there was no error code to return, so you might as well use the return value. But, oops, we have something else to return, and C has no tuples, so let's use an "out argument" instead.

We sometimes call this sort of thing "historical reasons". Your mileage may vary.

I *can* tell you that I personally would not design this function this way in, say, modern C++. But that's now, in 2018, and I don't make operating systems (oof, can you imagine? ).

At the end of the day, frankly, no harm was done.